# Opening chrome using docker to run selenium automation test

Tags: docker, automated-tests, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver

while running selenium tests locally, it automatically opens up the chrome browser to perform tasks. However, while running the same command from docker does not and the tests fails with below error.

**Unknown error: cannnot focus element**

**Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.**

```
kam-MBP: kl$ docker build -t dockerfinal .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  787.3MB
Step 1/3 : FROM dockerinit
 ---> 4d6fdb65d879
Step 2/3 : USER root

---> Using cache
 ---> 5fab69855211

Step 3/3 : RUN ./node_modules/.bin/wdio
 ---> Running in f55f142eabf3
------------------------------------------------------------------

[chrome #0-0] Session ID: 819c77057d6a7e274c8fbfd36858e3d9
[chrome #0-0] Spec: /tinderbox2_frontend/e2e/accproset.test.js
[chrome #0-0] Running: chrome

[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0] accountprojectsetting
[chrome #0-0]   1) "before each" hook for "should be able to do setting in account and project"
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0] **1 failing (30s)**

[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0] 1) accountprojectsetting "before each" hook for "should be able to do setting in account and project":
[chrome #0-0] **unknown error: cannot focus element**
[chrome #0-0] Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
[chrome #0-0]     at elementIdValue("0.17283645604924724-1", "testG1BDCgRtwowtEBp@moxion.rocks") - setValue.js:46:80
```

My **dockerinit** image docker file is below:

```
# setting base image
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

USER root

# Set the working directory to /tin_fe
WORKDIR /tin_fe

#Access to the project within docker container - Bundle app source
COPY . /tin_fe

# Install Node.js
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes curl

#configuring nodeSource repository to get enough version of nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

#configuring debian package repository 
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

#installing yarn 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y yarn 

#installing binary git package
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git

#running yarn
RUN yarn
```

Comment: well your docker container does not know anything about your local running chrome

Comment: But I am using `FROM selenium/standalone-chrome` in the docker file of  my base image i.e dockerinit. shouldn't it help to recognize that?

Comment: What's the Dockerfile look like?

Comment: added the dockerinit image docker file above